# In a custom action for Google Home, can the assistant listen for a keyword for a long time without answering?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

In a custom action for Google Home, can I create an intent where the assistant keeps listening for 10 minutes, waiting for a custom keyword without answering?

I looked into the docs and I couldn't find an answer but I guess that what I'm looking for is some kind of parameter that prevents the default answering behavior (when the user stops talking, the assistant answers back) and locks the assistant in listening mode.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. The Assistant is more designed for conversational interaction, and it isn't much of a conversation if it just sits there. It also raises privacy issues - Google is very concerned at the perception of having a permanently open mic recording everything and sending it to some third party.

I understand the use case, however. One thing you might consider is to return a small, quiet, beep to indicate you're still listening, but haven't heard anything to trigger on yet. You'd do this as both a fallback event (for when people don't say the keyword, but are speaking) and as a reprompt event. I haven't tested this sort of approach, however.

Comment: Thanks, I tried implementing something similar and it sort of works. 
I created an intent that returns an empty mp3 file if an entity is not recognized.